# i want to disable the cloud zoom module in drupal commerce kickstart

Tags: 7, commerce

[image]I am using Drupal Commerce kickstart. I including the demo site also. Cloud Zoom not working properly in my site, Please any one guide to me. I am new to Drupal commerce kickstart. I am using Drupal custom html theme convert to the Drupal theme.[image]

Cloudzoom module installed in core.
I can't disable it.

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem? If it is a module, why can't you just go to configuration -> modules and disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cloud Zoom](https://www.drupal.org/project/cloud_zoom) is a module included in the Commerce Kickstart distribution, if you want to disable it to replace it with something else, just go ahead and disable it in the drupal Modules admin page as Molot suggests.

Update: You can't just disable the module as it's part of the product dependencies in Kickstart.

So the only way you can disable its effects is in each place you see it, for example for the product page, under the Products menu, click on Variation types and then Manage display. Find the view mode, i.e. Full content, and disable/change the cloud zoom options.

[image]

More info: http://www.drupalcommerce.org/questions/7582/disable-cloud-zoom

Comment: Cloud Zoom moduleis a core module. I can't disable it.

Comment: I see what you mean, it's required by the products feature in kickstart, updating my answer